# Get link to image from asset library

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, file

I try to access an asset library in a SharePoint-Hosted App via the REST API. The app is hosted in SharePoint Online. I get the properties of the images (e.g. the title etc). But I do not find a property which contains a link to the image in SharePoint. Is there a way to get this?

Here is my code:

```
 public onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
     var listItemInfo = '';
     var listItemEnumerator = this.collListItems.getEnumerator();

     while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
         var oListItem: SP.ListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

         if (oListItem != null) {
             listItemInfo += "\nID: " + oListItem.get_id() +
                 "\nTitle: " + oListItem.get_item('Title');
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your REST query

```
$select=FileLeafRef
```